# why inline `push()` doesn't work on new created array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, chain

I am creating an `Array` with length of `1,000,000` and filling it with `1` like this:

```js
const bigArray = Array.from({ length: 1000000 }, () => 1);
```

when I push a new item to that `Array` just inline as bellow, `Nodejs` logs an error:

```js
// This rise an TypeError: bigArray.push is not a function
const bigArray = Array.from({ length: 1000000 }, () => 1).push(3);
```

```js
// Although this one works right
const bigArray = Array.from({ length: 1000000 }, () => 1);
bigArray.push(3)
```

[image]

Comment: "Nodejs logs an error" - cannot reproduce. Note, that `Array.prototype.push` does not return an array, so any consecutive calls would fail, but as described, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

[According to MDN](https://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), `Array#push` returns the new length of the array, not the array itself:

> Return value
> The new `length` property of the object upon which the method was called.

The code you provided works in any node engine otherwise.

Comment: thanks, I got that I should not consider the returned value of a `push` to be an array.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to that approach to keep things in one assignment, you could spread the array into a new array:

```
const bigArray = [...Array.from({ length: 1000000 }, () => 1), 3];
```

Comment: Thanks, it works as a solution for the changing and inline case.

Comment: aka "create the array twice, making a huge data copy (implied by the 1000000 elements), for no reason at all". Sure, if it's small, or in a place where performance is irrelevant... but getting into the habit of always doing this, better not.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I think so, but it is reasonable that the `.push()` should add item exactly after array creation and should return just the array after that.

Comment: @ASDFGerte, I appreciate the comment about keeping an eye on performance. I did some performance tests on numerous benchmarking sites. If performance is critical, then you should use a for-loop to push to an empty array and use neither of these approaches. I benchmarked three approaches: 1: Create using For-loop: 193 ops/s. 2: Array.from then .push: 41 ops/s. 3: Spread Array.from into literal (my solution above): 40 ops/s. Here is [a benchmark](https://jsben.ch/HiL8G) with these tests